# Regarding load test not executing properly in azure pipelines

Tags: jmeter, webdriver, azure-pipelines, load-testing, taurus

I am running load rest in azure pipelines. jmeter script contains 2 thread group. 1st thread group has single user, it contains one web driver sampler named as login to environment. When i ran test this sampler opens the chrome browser, logins the user and closes the browser immediately. After that apis placed under another thread group executes. This login to environment web driver executed only for once during test execution. But from last 2 days when i ran azure pipeline test, this login to environment web driver sampler executes successfully first time. And instead of going flow to another thread group, this web driver sampler executes again and fails. thus test doest not proceed further and remaining apis of another thread group does not gets executes. Build keep running for build timeout time(1 hour)and gets cancelled. what could be the issue, below are the results which i see in artifacts for that web driver sampler.

LoginToEnvironment  2   1   50.00%  50600.50    9382    91819   50600.50    91819.00    91819.00    91819.00    0.02    3.24    0.00

web driver sampler login to environment is working fine locally and its getting executed only once. Issue occurs in pipelines only.

i checked script and no issue seems to be from script end, as script working fine locally. What could be the reason that is causing login to envioronment web driver sampler to execute twice in jmeter run tauras

Answer (score 0):

We cannot state what could be the reason for 2nd execution of the WebDriver Sampler without seeing:

1. Your [Taurus YAML](https://gettaurus.org/docs/YAMLTutorial/) configuration file
2. Your JMeter [.jmx script](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JmxTestPlan)
3. [`jmeter.log`](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging) and `bzt.log` files from [Artifacts directory](https://gettaurus.org/docs/ArtifactsDir/)